# What question is my computer asking me?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

I need your help. I think my computer is gaining sentience. I went to a play, but when I got back this file was saved on my desktop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: latin8 -*-
i = input("Please enter a character: ")
print((i == "Ä" or i == ";"))
```

*(note: The original riddle had a colon `:` instead of a semicolon `;`. This was my fault, the correct character is a semicolon)*

It was saved as `question.py`. I know I didn't write this! I think my computer is trying to ask me a question, but I can't tell what the question is.

What question is my computer asking me?

---

To avoid confusing people, this is not a unicode trick. The "Ä" character is encoded as a single byte, `0xC4`.

Hint:

> The question is a famous line

Comment: Also, I'm really new to puzzling.se, so if there's anything I should do differently, let me know.

Comment: Well, technically, it's asking you to 'Please enter a character'.  I think you're looking for something less obvious though.

Comment: To make it clearer: the program, when launched, will request a text input from the user, and respond `True` for `Ä` or `:` and `False` otherwise.

Comment: Sounds more like a programming-related question than a puzzle. This prints True if what you enter is either a colon or a dotted A, and False otherwise. Or is there something more to it?

Comment: Is your file *actually* encoded in Latin-8? Because it makes a huge difference in how it works (saved in UTF-8, it doesn't recognize the Ä unless you remove the second line).

Comment: @AimanAl-Eryani Yes there is more to it. It's supposed to be a riddle similar to this one: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30064/11338

Comment: @BaSzAt Yes, it actually is saved in Latin8, and that is important and relevant.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-14 link to the codepahe

Comment: Those are characters 0xC4 and 0x3A in the Latin-8 encoding. (In particular, they are regrettably not 0x2B and ~0x2B.) In decimal, 196 and 58.

Comment: "Give me plastic explosives or give me emergency roadside service"

Comment: Slightly oddly, 0xC4 and 0x3A are *pretty close* to being complements like 0x2B and ~0x2B. And for that matter 0x2B and 0x3A aren't so very different: just let one nybble lend 1 to the other. I expect this is all just coincidence, but maybe there's some clever thing I'm missing.

Comment: @DJ McMayhem, when you read that file and see e.g. "Ä" are you doing so in the Latin-8 encoding? Or might we e.g. be treating it as UTF-8?

Comment: If the file looks like that when treated as UTF-8, then that "Ä" string is actually 0xC3 0x84. In Latin-8 the first of those is a capital A with tilde and the second is left undefined by ISO-8859-8 and typical Microsoft conventions would make it a "lower" European double-quotation-mark. None of that seems likely to be helpful.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That's already been addressed here, It's Latin-8

Comment: No, what's been established here is that the file *is* Latin-8, not that the text we see above is the result of *treating it as* Latin-8. If your text editor doesn't understand the "-\*- coding: -\*-" convention then it might pick a different encoding, in which case what we're seeing as "Ä" might be interpreted as something else by the Python interpreter.

Comment: For that matter, if you run that program in a context where whatever's supplying input to the Python interpreter (e.g., a terminal emulator running under X on Linux, etc.) isn't using the Latin-8 encoding, then what you need to type to get something that reaches the Python interpreter as the Latin-8 encoding of "Ä" may be something entirely other than "Ä".

Comment: I should add that I don't actually think this sort of trickery is likely to be the point of the question, and I rather hope it isn't.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, you've spent a lot of time and effort going after something that is most certainly not part of the puzzle

Comment: A couple of minutes only, actually.

Comment: ... As you will see from the original questioner's comments on Caelan O'Toole's answer, it turns out it *wasn't* coincidence that 0xC4 and 0x3A are almost complements, and they were actually intended to be exactly complements :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a guess:

> Could your computer be asking the question: "To be or not to be?" from Shakespeare's *Hamlet*?  My reasoning was simmilar to Caelan's, except I expected to get the Hex value `0x2B` from ord('Ä'), but it was giving me 196 (`0xC4`), and I didn't think to divide by two. If I did so, I would have found that the unicode encoding was 'b', `chr(196/2) == 'b'`, but I just didn't have time to think through my answer, and posted this guess on a hunch. However, looking back If you take `unichr(59)` which is the `~` (binary `NOT`) operation of the hex value `'0xc4'` (~196 is negative).

Comment: Interesting, this might be it, but please explain your thoughts.

Comment: 2B is '+' and ~2B is is 'Ô'

Comment: Great guess. What's your reasoning?

Comment: You got this first therefore are getting my upvote, if you had added an explanation this would have been accepted for sure

Comment: @Caelan Updated answer with reasoning, includes reasoning for ";" as well.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem My answer has been updated to show how to get ';'.

Answer (score 6):

> To be or not to be? (Well, more "2b or not 2b")

My reasoning:

> The unicode code for Ä is U+00C4. The key part here is C4.
>  If we translate C4 from hexadecimal to decimal, we get the number 196. Half of 196 is 98.
>  Let's now translate 98 from decimal to hexadecimal to get 62, and look for unicode code U+0062.
>  The letter that comes out is b. Note that 196 being 2 times 98 is where the two comes from.
>  Whatever you do for the colon, you will come to something that is not 2b.

Comment: Your last line makes no sense though because anything you type will be 'not' (answer) but only a colon is accepted as 'true'

Comment: Oh, wait, I didn't read the comments on the question correctly. Ä and : are true, nothing else.

Comment: Your reasoning for the first part makes sense though, whether it's right or not, good stuff

Comment: You're trying to make your explanation adapt to an answer, while it should be vice versa.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. This is *spot on* except for the part about the colon. However, (and this is *completely* my fault) I messed up the riddle. It should be a semicolon `;` instead or a colon `:`. I'm not really sure what I should do. Should I update the riddle and wait for somebody to explain the semicolon also, or should I explain my mistake and accept this one (since the only part it's missing is my fault)?

Comment: I think you should accept this and explain that ';' = ~'Ä' more explicitly in comments.

Comment: `;` is 3B in Unicode, so I guess that explains it?

Comment: SlashmanX, the point is that 0x3B = ~0xC4. (And 0xC4 = 2*0x62 = 2*'b', which is the actual key point of the question.) [note: when I wrote this, SlashmanX's comment said something a bit different from what it says now.]

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Just a coincidence I guess (or just completely irrelevant). I edited my comment cos there was possibly a spoiler in it

Comment: @DJ McMayhem, to clarify my comment ("I think you should ...") above: I think you should *also* update the riddle, but leave a note in there saying what it originally said and that this is why lots of the discussion talks about ':' rather than ';'.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Done. Sorry about that, I feel really bad now.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole I'm accepting this answer because "2b or not 2b. Yes, *that* is the question."

Comment: I already thought it was meant to be semicolon. That was 3b. I couldn't figure out how 3a related to the question.

Comment: Really disappointed to see this being marked as the answer. Take half? I can't find any hint in the puzzle that tells you to do this. To leave out the ":"? Meh. Basically, this puzzle wouldn't have been solved without making a blind guess about what the answer would be and going towards that.

Comment: but the semicolon is 59, which is ~196 - it's not just that 3B is "not 2B"

Comment: Yes, the second half of the explanation is very wrong. I don't know if I should unaccept this since I've already screwed this up so much.

Comment: Add your own explanation to the answer then, as I couldn't think of much better.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Unaccept my answer and instead accept micsthepick answer instead. It is more complete than mine.

Answer (score 1):

> Your computer is developing emotions. The question is 'Do you love me?', and it is offering two choices; A (grade A YES) or a colon (taken to be NO)

Comment: I think a colon is yes (or True)

Comment: @MohitJain; OP has changed the Q since my answer - i was using the medical colon as a metaphor

Comment: Still the output of the program is same. True of a `:`

Comment: @MohitJain; yes so you are only allowed to enter A or : or the computer will see your response as a lie - they are only binary creatures after all

Comment: Yes, makes sense.